# how to fix an element's position and scale its size when the browser's window is resizing?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, responsive-design

I would like to know how can I fix an element's position contained in a div, and adjust its size when the browser's window is resizing.
Here is my code:

```
var principale = document.getElementsByClassName("postItSet")[0];
var card = document.createElement('div');
card.className = "card";
card.setAttribute("id", "mydiv" + id1);

var cardBlock = document.createElement('div');
cardBlock.className ="card-block";

var cardTitle = document.createElement('div');
cardTitle.className = "card-title";
if (this.model.choice == true) {
   cardTitle.innerHTML = "anonymous"
}
else {
   cardTitle.innerHTML = this.profil.user.prenom + "";
}

var cardText = document.createElement('div');
cardText.className = "card-text";
cardText.setAttribute("id", "mydivheader");
cardText.innerHTML = self.model.contenu;

cardBlock.appendChild(cardTitle);
cardBlock.appendChild(cardText);
card.appendChild(cardBlock);
principale.appendChild(card);
principale.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

Here is the css :

```
var st = document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0];
st.innerHTML = ".card {position:fixed ;z-index: 9;background-color: #f1f1f1;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;cursor: grab; word-wrap: break-word; width:auto; }";
st.innerHTML += ".cardBlock {padding: 10px;cursor: grab; z-index: 10;background-color: #2196F3; color: #fff;  word-wrap: break-word;}";
```

I would like to make my page responsive. My goal is to add drag'n'drop "card" elements on a specific background image and be able to keep their position even if we resize the browser's window. I've tried many things, but in major cases, my cards loose their draggable-dropable properties.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You'd need to use css media queries.

Comment: Well, you can set the `left`, `top`, `width` and `height` properties in vw and vh units.

Comment: I don't see any sizes... did you search for vw/vh-sizes (size in percent of viewport)?

Comment: To be more precise here an example: if we have an background image which is diplaying a grid, like this [link](https://cdn.strategyzer.com/assets/marketing/canvases-business-model-canvas-a8509296e3cd543ee7c6881cada7082376d4dfdf4eac40e849490c0dba2d178b.svg) , and if a card is on a specific column, I would like to be able to repositioning it on the correct column, when the window is resized.
I use width, height and size attributes for the background image only. I also tried to use "resize event"